# absolute centered div not overflowing correctly

Tags: html, css

Take a look a this sample HTML (a dumbed-down version of my project):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .pagewrapper {
                width: 960px;
                height: 768px;
                margin: auto;
                border: 1px solid green;
                border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgb(0, 153, 51);
            }
            .pagewrapperImg {
                background: url("http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg");
                background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: scroll;">
        <div style="right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="pagewrapper pagewrapperImg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is suppose to produce a centered div with a background image. When the window is resized, it should overflow with scrollbars. This works fine on Firefox, but on IE and chrome, it clips the top of the div, as shown in the image.

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

**EDIT**: Let me point out that in the full project, there are UI elements in this div, and they get clipped too (it's not just the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `.pagewrapperImg` add

```
background-position:center center;
```

and please please please....dont use `inline` styles!!

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3y9x5wL/)

Comment: the inlined styles are there so u can just copy-paste the code into a sample file and run it

Comment: @MarioStoilov : yup and that helped me....but please don't add it in you original source code....did my solution helped? :)

Comment: sadly, no :(. The situation remains the same

Comment: is page live somewhere?

Comment: [**does this fiddle looks as per your requirement on chrome?**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3y9x5wL/)

Comment: @MarioStoilov : i dint changed anything...just removed those inline divs! :)

Comment: you added the `html,body {  
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}`, which solved the problem

Comment: @MarioStoilov : thats rule of thumb for `css` mate...anyway, i added the fiddle..! :D